# Mongoose - Push an object into a nested array after matching element

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

I am trying to push an object into an array after finding the matching element within the array of objects.

This is an example of what the structure of my playlist collection looks like:

```
playlist: {
    userName: 'user-name',
    userId: 'user-id',
    playlistArray: [
        {
            playlistName: 'playlist1',
            playlistSongs: [
                { track: '', title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { track: '', title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { track: '', title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
            ],
        },
        {
            playlistName: 'playlist2',
            playlistSongs: [
                { track: '', title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { track: '', title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { track: '', title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
            ],
        },
    ],
}
```

and this is the object I am trying to insert into the `playlistSongs` array that also contains `playlistName: 'playlist2'` within the same object.

```
{ track: 'sometrackinfo', title: 'sometracktitle', duration: 123, uri: 'sometrackuri' }
```

So the result would look like this:

```
playlist: {
    userName: 'user-name',
    userId: 'user-id',
    playlistArray: [
        {
            playlistName: 'playlist1',
            playlistSongs: [
                { track: '', title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { track: '', title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { track: '', title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
            ],
        },
        {
            playlistName: 'playlist2',
            playlistSongs: [
                { track: '', title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { track: '', title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { track: '', title: '', duration: 0, uri: '' },
                { track: 'sometrackinfo', title: 'sometracktitle', duration: 123, uri: 'sometrackuri' },
            ],
        },
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `arrayFilters` and filtered `$[<identifier>]` operator.

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  "$push": {
    "playlist.playlistArray.$[pl].playlistSongs": {
      track: "sometrackinfo",
      title: "sometracktitle",
      duration: 123,
      uri: "sometrackuri"
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "pl.playlistName": "playlist2"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RYlvI6_vDaJ)